# Regex to find texts between nested parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have a very long string which has nested loops. I want to extract a pattern in that.

**String_Text:**

```
some random texts......
........................
........................
{{info .................
.....texts..............
...{{ some text }}...... // nested parenthesis 1
........................
...{{ some text }}...... // nested parenthesis 2
........................
}} // End of topmost parenthesis
........................
..again some random text
........................
........................ // can also contain {{  }}
......End of string.
```

I want to extract all the text between the topmost parenthesis i.e.

**Extracted_string:**

```
info .................
.....texts..............
...{{ some text }}...... // nested parenthesis 1
........................
...{{ some text }}...... // nested parenthesis 2
........................
```

**Pattern:**

> 1.) starts with **{** and can be followed by any number of **{**.
>
> 2.) After that there can be any number of ***white space***.
>
> 3.) The first word after that is surely ***info***.
>
> 4.) Extract till this bracket is not closed.

What is have tried so far:

`re.findall(r'\{+[^\S\r\n]*info\s*(.*(?:\r?\n.*)*)\}+')`

I know this is wrong as what this does is find the last instance of **}** in the string. Can someone help me out in extracting text between those bracket? TIA

Comment: Can you leverage the context here and match up to the first `}}` that are on a separate line? Like `re.findall(r'(?sm)^{{[^\S\r\n]*info\s*(.*?)^}}$', s)`?

Comment: Wow! This works. Thanks a lot! can you explain me though how it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around pattern can be the one that matches a line starting with `{{info`  and then matches any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the line with just `}}` on it:

```
re.findall(r'(?sm)^{{[^\S\r\n]*info\s*(.*?)^}}$', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hYgwRO/1/).

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - `re.DOTALL` (now, `.` matches a newline) and `re.MULTILINE` (`^` now matches line start and `$` matches line end positions) flags
- `^` - start of a line
- `{{` - a `{{` substring
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `info` - a substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `^}}$` - start of a line, `}}` and end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a recursive approach:

```
{
    ((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)
}
```

This is only supported by the newer `regex` module, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7xzrZt/1/).

Comment: This  might overmatch since OP only expects to extract the contents of `{{info...}}` substrings. And you cannot just add `info` after the first `{` in `{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)}`.

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot. It does work but it matches all the {{ }} strings, I didn't want that. I even upvoted your answer but I found the answer by Wiktor to be the most suitable,  hence I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19863847/7434365) explains how to do this with recursion (albeit for round brackets, but easily adaptable), however, personally, I would just write it using a while-loop:

```
b = 1
i = si = s.index('{')
i += 1
while b:
    if s[i] == '{': b += 1
    elif s[i] == '}': b -=1
    i += 1

ss = s[si:i]
```

where, with your string defined as: `s`, gives the substring, `ss`, as:

```
>>> print(ss)
{{info .................
.....texts..............
...{{ some text }}...... // nested parenthesis 1
........................
...{{ some text }}...... // nested parenthesis 2
........................
}}
```